# Add a unique field and fill it

Tags: elixir, database-migration, phoenix-framework

I'm working with Elixir and Phoenix, I have a table and I want to add a new field to this table but I want this field to be unique. Since my DataBase already have a bunch of register in this table I want to fill the new field with the value from another field of the table.

For example, the table it's posts, I'm adding the new field name, which would be uniqe, and want that all the old register fill the field name with the value in the field email.

How can I do this ? Do I do it in the migration ? like:

```
def change do
  alter table(:posts) do
    add :name, :string, null: false, default: :email
  end

  create unique_index(:posts, [:name])
end
```

or in the model ?

Please a little help in her would be great thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Ecto's `update_all` to do this:

```
alias Myapp.Repo
alias Myapp.Post
import Ecto.Query

from(p in Post, update: [set: [name: p.old_name]])
|> Repo.update_all([])
```

Being old_name your old field and name the field where you want the old value.

See `Ecto.Query` docs https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3

Comment: Excelent, this helps a lot. Thanks